# Records in Subreports Are Not Displayed In 1st Page of Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

Details Section Is Not Displayed In 1st Page of Crystal Report

Structure of my crystal report:

```
Report Header 
Page Header 
Group Header 
Report Footer - contains 2 subreports
```

When records in my subreports are more than one page, there are no data displayed in my subreports in the first page, subreport data start in the second page.
When there are few records in the subreports (ex: 1 or 2 records only), it is displayed in the first page.

Am I missing some settings here? I don't really know what to do here...Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should look at your settings in the **Section Expert**, specifically you may need to turn off the **Keep Together** option for your Report Footer and your subreports.  If the data takes up more than 1 page, this option will attempt to keep the data in that section together by moving it all to the next page.
2. Also, to help keep your data on the same page, try suppressing unused subreport sections.

Answer (score 6):

From the main report, you can also check under 'Format Subreport', the 'Common' tab has a box for 'Keep Object Together'. Uncheck that to allow the subreport itself to break into multiple parts

Answer (score 1):

This one stumped me for a bit - right click on the subreport and select Format Subreport. On the Common tab near the bottom you'll see Keep Object Together, which for me was checked by default. Uncheck this and the subreport will start on page 1.

Comment: This answer is the clearest because it explains that the Keep Object Together is on the Format Sub Report window because there are other Keep Together options in the Section Expert!

Answer (score 0):

Right click your SubReport > Change Subreport Links. Make sure you have chosen one field from the "Available fields" section.

Hope it helps.